# Angular for liveapp development

Tags: quip, liveapps

I notice among Quip's liveapps [examples](https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/tree/master/examples/jquery-stub), one that uses JQuery instead of React. Since I am quite familiar with Angular, I'm wondering if one could also use Angular in place of JQuery to build a liveapp.

I am uncertain because I notice that even the JQuery example, while not dependent on React, nevertheless still uses a .jsx template, so I'm not sure whether that is a requirement of the build environment.

I would assume that as long as the quip library is imported, the underlying javascript functions that implement its methods should not matter, correct?

Comment: Not an answer, but someone has found how to use [React+Angular](https://blog.rapid7.com/2016/02/03/combining-angularjs-and-reactjs-for-better-applications/), so I'd say it's at least within the realm of possibility, but I have no inclination to try something like that tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Digging around in the node_modules folder, it seems like what I am asking would indeed be feasible, but it would require writing a new webpack.config.js file that would transpile the Angular-specific artifacts into the final app.js file in the dist folder, that then gets compiled into the final app.ele file.

As I am not all that familiar with Webpack and the necessary steps required by the quip modules to achieve this, I hope the Quip Dev team will see to it to make it possible to develop liveapps with other popular javascript frameworks such as Angular to expand its ecosystem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your assessment is right on a Live App can easily be built in AngularJS. We've had partners doing vanilla javascript, jQuery, and typescript so it really amounts to the fact that you can use anything you want to generate `js_files` and/or `css_files` and then point to those in your `manifest.json` - See https://corp.quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation#app-manifest